# Dedicated window for dired mode in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, dired

I have emacs behaving more or less how I want it to by using this common bit of elisp:

```
(defun toggle-current-window-dedication ()
 (interactive)
 (let* ((window    (selected-window))
        (dedicated (window-dedicated-p window)))
   (set-window-dedicated-p window (not dedicated))
   (message "Window %sdedicated to %s"
            (if dedicated "no longer " "")
            (buffer-name))))

(global-set-key [pause] 'toggle-current-window-dedication)
```

Unfortunately, dired uses the directory for the buffer name, so dedicating a dired window only dedicates it to that directory.  Once you navigate up or down, it opens a new buffer in a separate window.  What I would like to do is dedicate a window to a major mode (dired in this case), and have all new buffers that default to that mode prefer that window.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using your code in combination with [`dired-single`](http://www.northbound-train.com/emacs/dired-single.el), which will cause all dired navigation to happen within a single buffer named `*dired*`.  In the interests of full disclosure, I wrote `dired-single`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `dired-single` opens the files in the same window as the `*dired*` buffer. While this is perfect for directories, it would be nice if files could be treated like with `dired-find-file-other-window`...

Comment: Joe, did this project move to https://github.com/crocket/dired-single? Your link is now dead.

Comment: I did not move it there, but it looks like someone else did, which is OK by me. Unfortunately, I do not use Emacs any longer, so I don't have a means to support this project.

Answer (score 3):

`set-window-dedicated-p` forces Emacs to only show that window for that buffer, the other dired buffers cannot use the same window.  See the [*info* page for `set-window-dedicated-p`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dedicated-Windows.html#Dedicated-Windows):

> `display-buffer' (*note Choosing
>   Window::) never uses a dedicated
>   window for displaying another buffer
>   in it.

Perhaps one of the packages on the wiki page for [DiredReuseDirectoryBuffer](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredReuseDirectoryBuffer) provides the functionality you're looking for...

Comment: Thanks, Trey.  I am using dired-find-alternate-file to prevent new buffers from being opened, and I set up a same-window-regexps for dired buffers.  This gets me 90% of where I want to be, but other buffers can still open in my dired window (help, completions, etc).  If I had a better grasp of elisp I would just hook a regexp match for dired in a window before opening a new buffer in it.  :)